# A JavaScript RegExp question

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you guys help me figure this out? I have the following JavaScript snippet:

```
pattern = new RegExp('^bla*a', 'i');
console.debug(pattern.exec('blatr'));
```

After I run this, the output is ["bla"].
The way I interpret this regular expression is this: find me a string that starts with 'bla' and ends with 'a', with as many characters in between. In this case, 'blatr' shouldn't match the regular expression but it does.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why my answer wasn't picked? (I want to know purely for personal academic analysis, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **a*** in your expression is matching the preceding character **a** zero or more times, not the string **bla**. You'll need to use parentheses. Try this:

```
new RegExp('(^bla){1}.+a$', 'i');
```

**EDIT:** No point in using + in an expression that matches the beginning of a string. Also, since you say you want to match any characters in between **bla** and **a** you'll need to use a + after the .

**EDIT:** Ahem, seems one doesn't need parentheses either as the other answers show. Note to self: Stop over-engineering your RegEx's and test your answers before you post them. :P This is fine:

```
new RegExp('^bla.+a$', 'i');
```

Answer (score 4):

A '*' signifies {0,} or "0 or more" of the preceding character. What you're trying to do should be

```
^bla.*a$
```

*edit*: missed the "ends with 'a'" part of the question earlier.

Comment: Just append $ to end of this regex, otherwise it match "blatraddd" also.

Comment: Missed that part in the question. Corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches the letters `bl` at the beginning of the line followed by zero or more `a`'s and then one `a` (which is equivalent to one or more `a`'s) with possibly characters following that. `blatr` matches that.

To do what you want to do (if I understand correctly, use:

`'^bla.*a'`

The `*` means repeat the previous character zero or more times